# Make filters of an object list

Tags: python, django, filter, tags

I get from my database a list of objects with attributes. So I want to make dynamics filters on the left depends of my list results.

For example, if i have an advertisement on "Paris" and "New York" i want to see Paris(1), New york (1) on the left. When you click on it, you will see just Paris' advertisement or New york's.

What is the best way to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q
Advertisement.objects.filter( Q(name = 'Paris') | Q(name = 'New York') )
```

You need to use [filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) and [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset

exemple:

```
cities = City.objects.annotate(ads_count=Count("adevertissement"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i didn't understand the documentation. For me, each advertissement has a city_name (string), how can I get with aggregation all the differents city_name with the count? Something like : {{'paris': 10},{'new york' : 12}}